# insertar campos en laravel de una base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ionic

estoy intentando insertar en una tabla que llamo 'standout_product' de mysql una serie de datos que obtengo de una otra tabla productos, primero realizo un array para obtener los productos de una tabla que tiene un campo 'standout' el cual ha de estar en '1' con todos los otros campos  del producto. hasta aquí no hay problema lo obtengo y lo imprimo en pantalla, lo que no me resulta es que necesito que la tabla standout_product se rellene automáticamente con el product_id de los productos que estandout es igual a 1 junto con tres campos más, active que será 0 en un principio y dos fechas.

la idea es obtener estos datos en una tabla para después crear un sistema que los 20 primeros de esa tabla se muestren en pantalla 1hora y después a la otra hora mostrar los 20 siguientes y por ahora intento crear esa tabla y no puedo.

este es el código es laravel esta en la api de mi aplicación de ionic.
el modelo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
 

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class standoutproduct extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table = 'standout_product';
    protected $primaryKey = "product_id";

    public $timestamps = false;


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'active', 
        'loop_date',
        'print_date'
    ];
  
}
```

El controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Models\Standoutproduct;
use App\Models\Product;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Users;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;


class StandoutProductController extends Controller {
  
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

      public function __construct()   {

    }

   public function get_all_product_standout(Request $request){
        $result=$this->check_usertoken($request->user_id,$request->api_token);        
        if(!$result)    {
            return response()->json(['status'=>'0', 'msg'=>'Algo ha salido mal.']);
        }







       
        $tmp_list =  Product::join('users','users.user_id','=','product.user_id')
        ->join('category','category.category_id','=','product.category_id')
        ->select('product.*','users.firstname','users.lastname','users.image as user_image','users.mobile as user_mobile','users.lat','users.lng','users.address','category.title as category_title')
        ->where('product.status','active')->where('product.standout','1')->get(); 

       
        $product_list=array();

        foreach($tmp_list as $val){      
            if($val->address!='')
            $val->address=json_decode($val->address);

            $tmp_filelist=json_decode($val->image_list);
            $result_filelist=[];
            if( $tmp_filelist && count($tmp_filelist)>0){
                foreach($tmp_filelist as $tmp){
                    if ($tmp && $tmp!='')  {
                        $tmp->file_url= $this->site_url.$tmp->file_path;                    
                        $result_filelist[]=$tmp;
                    }                           
                }
            }
            $val->image_list=$result_filelist;

            if( $val->user_image!=''){
                $val->user_image = $this->site_url. "public/uploads/users/".$val->user_image;  
            }else{
                $val->user_image ='';
            }

            $product_list[] = $val;
        }
        $product_list = array_slice ($product_list, 0, 20);

        $data=$product_list;   
       

        return response()->json(['status'=>'1', 'msg'=>'success','data' => $data]);     
    }
```

Esto funciona crea un array con 20 productos pero despues intente insertar esto para crear la tabla y  solo me da errores lo inserte en el controlador despues de $data=$product_list;

```
   $standoutproduct=product::find($request->product_id);
    $timestamp = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
      
   standout_product::create([
        
        'product_id'    =>  $standoutproduct->product_id,
        'active'        => '1',
        'loop_date'     => $timestamp,
        'print_date'    => $timestamp,
        
    ]);
```

Comment: Y que error te dá? Por lo pronto veo el modelo se llama `standoutproduct`, pero para insertar veo que pusiste `standout_product`

Comment: puedes mostrar el diagrama de modelo entidad relación para entender que deseas hacer

Comment: Hola buenas creo que lo estoy haciendo mal necesito pasar los campos de la tabla productos con standout 1 a la tabla standout_product, para después recuperarlos y mostrar los 20 primeros y pasado una hora mostrar los 20 siguientes y que el ciclo se vaya repitiendo creo que lo estoy haciendo mal no se alguna ayuda porfavor.